# Notify in .NET application if SQL data has changed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, sqldependency

I have got two tables. Table A contains the main data in every change state, Table B has the detail data.

---

Table A
| ID | Name |
|  1 | House |
|  2 | Tree |
|  3 | Car |

Table B
| ID | FK | DateTime | Color | Type |
|  1 | 1 | 2017-26-01T13:00:00 | Red | Bungalow |
|  2 | 2 | 2017-26-01T13:05:00 | Brown | Oak |
|  3 | 1 | 2017-26-01T13:10:00 | Green | Bungalow |
|  4 | 3 | 2017-26-01T13:15:00 | Yellow | Smart |
|  5 | 1 | 2017-26-01T13:20:00 | White | Bungalow |
|  6 | 3 | 2017-26-01T13:25:00 | Black | Smart |

---

Result to watch
| ID | Name | DateTime | Color | Type |
|  1 | House | 2017-26-01T13:20:00 | White | Bungalow |
|  2 | Tree | 2017-26-01T13:05:00 | Brown | Oak |
|  3 | Car | 2017-26-01T13:25:00 | Black | Smart |

---

The current state of an entity in Table A is described by the record with the youngest timestamp in Table B.

Now, I want to be nofitied, if an entity gets a new state (new record in Table B) or a new entity is created (new records in Table A and B), i.e. it could look like.

---

New result to watch
| ID | Name | DateTime | Color | Type |
| 1 | House | 2017-26-01T13:20:00 | White | Bungalow |
| 2 | Tree | 2017-26-01T13:05:00 | Brown | Oak |
| 3 | Car | 2017-26-01T19:25:00 | Silver | Smart |
| 4 | Dog | 2017-26-01T20:25:00 | White / Black | Poodle |

---

With `SqlDependency` it is not possible to be notified for a statement which contains `GROUP BY` with `MAX` aggregate, window functions or `TOP` clause. So I have no idea how I can get the last detail data for an entity.

Is there any possibility to create a statement for this requirement or are there any other ways to be notified after changes for this result?

Comment: Not that you have not though of it but get a notification on TableB and then manually run the proper query or just do the group by in .NET

Answer (score 0):

You can create and use SQL Triggers usin CLR

Here - [SQL Trigger CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/938d9dz2.aspx)